# Are entitlements required to for appA to execute an AppleScript that launches appB?

Tags: applescript, code-signing, entitlements, osx-gatekeeper

We have two signed Mac OS X apps (that we developed — non "app store" apps).  appA runs an Applescript (from a .scpt file) that sends appB a message to launch and search for some text.

This works perfectly on OS X 10.6.

On OS X 10.7 and 10.8, I get a different behavior:  when appA runs the Applescript, appB WILL NOT LAUNCH. However, if appB is ALREADY RUNNING, then appA's message IS received by appB and the requested search is processed.

This seems like a sandbox issue: when we issued this command to Terminal:

```
sudo spctl --master-disable
```

…and restart, there is also no problem with the Applescript launching appB on 10.8.  On 10.7, appB will still not launch.

Do we need TEMPORARY ENTITLEMENTS to be able to execute an AppleScript script (or send AppleEvents) to our other app?  Both apps are manually signed using codesign.  Are these entitlements obtained from Developer Relations and applied with codesign?

appA gets the AppleScript and executes it through the following functions:

```
OpenDefaultComponent(), OSALoad(), AEBuildAppleEvent(), OSAExecuteEvent()
```

The AppleScript being executed is:

```
on lookup(search_phrase)

tell application "appB"
activate
lookup (search_phrase)
end tell
end lookup

property ASDScriptUniqueIdentifier : "Lookup.scpt"
```

Comment: You don't say if your apps are sandboxed.  If they are not sandboxed, then entitlements are not the problem.  I would start by looking for errors reported (a) in your code that executes the AppleScript script, and (b) in the system Console.  My guess is that the AppleScript code is failing to find "appB".  You could try using bundle IDs instead of app names in the tell statement to make the app lookup more robust.

Comment: @MarkAlldritt -- Will try that, but it still doesn't explain why it has failed on 10.7 and 10.8 -- or why turning off gatekeeper completely resolves the problem on 10.8.

Comment: @MarkAlldritt -- Editing the Tell application in "appB" to change it to its bundle ID ("com.writebros.appB") causes the AppleScript Editor to ask to resolve the bundle ID when I go to save changes.

I've noticed that one additional issue is that on 10.8 once the appB launches, it immediately disappears (is hidden).  However, if I do a SECOND activate (after the lookup) then appB WILL be brought forward.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about that, but you can if appB is an Applescript (really a *script*, not an app).

Then you could use (in AppA):

```
set AppB to load script alias "path:to:app:B"
set scriptResult to AppB's theaction() --Change theaction to your needs
```

This way, you would load appB into appA, causing appA actually to perform the action.

Comment: appA and appB are both Carbon Mach-O executable applications.